# Silverlight web application loading an external page in the app

Tags: html, vb.net, silverlight, iframe

Basically i have an application that needs to be able to navigate to a webpage on the app whilst in the browser in silverlight how can i go about doing this?

It does not let me use the web browser tool and i cannot find any other way. I dont think i will be able to use an iframe either as i need to be able to draw a canvas over the webpage that can then be drawn upon using a paint tool and i dont think using an iframe will allow this.

So how do i go about getting an external website to load inside of my web silverlight application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, there is a `WebBrowser` control but it is only available when running in out of browser mode.

I'm afraid at the moment, the only way is by using an Iframe (spent many hours searching).

I managed to get it working OK by using this tutorial: [Showing HTML content inside silverlight app](http://blog.gfader.com/2010/05/silverlight-showing-html-content-inside.html)

However for your requirements (drawing on top of the webpage) this will not work, as it does not allow the Silverlight app to integrate with the html content.

The only option that i can think of is setting your app be be out of browser, then using the `WebBrowser` control

*But this will not be appropriate as i've just noticed that your app needs to be accessible through a browser!*

Comment: Thanks for the response, so by going by this its not really possible to achieve what i want to achieve then?

Comment: As far as i know, no. That's why i made the decision to re think my application & develop it using html5 instead. If you do find a solution, i would be interested in seeing it. But just to let you know, i did spend quite a lot of time researching this.

Comment: Yes i was researching for a good few hours but as you said i have decided to turn to html5 for this section of my app